# Password value object that can be either hashed or raw

Tags: php, validation, hash, domain-driven-design, value-objects

I've got the following value object (VO) `Password`. The password must be between 6 and 20 characters. But since my `UserMapper` is hashing the password before persisting the entity, I have no idea what validation logic I should have in this VO.

When `UserMapper` returns a `User`, the password is in a hashed form which is 60 characters long.

Does that mean I have to take into consideration both of these scenarios in my value object? Currently it would throw an `InvalidArgumentException` exception because the value would not be between 6 and 20 chars but 60 characters long (hashed).

```
namespace Models\Values\User;

use \InvalidArgumentException;

class Password
{
    private $min = 6;
    private $max = 20;

    private $password;

    public function __construct($password)
    {
        if (is_string($password) && !empty($password)) {
            $length = $this->stringLength($password);

            if ($length >= $this->min && $length <= $this->max) {
                $this->password = $password;
            }
        } else {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('%s must be a string from %s to %s characters.', __METHOD__, $this->min, $this->max));
        }
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    private function stringLength($string)
    {
        $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($string);
        $length   = mb_strlen($string, $encoding);

        return $length;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not differ between `HashedPassword` and `Password`?

Comment: I'm still relatively new to DDD, but that would mean either one of them would be `null` at all times. When registering the `HashedPassword` would be null, and when logging in `Password` would be null. Is it okay to have null values in an entity?

Comment: I'm inexperienced in DDD as well, was just a thought as a hashed password and a password are bascially different things

Comment: Also see Openwall's [PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) (PHPass). Its portable and hardened against a number of common attacks on user passwords. The guy who wrote the framework (SolarDesigner) is the same guy who wrote [John The Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) and sits as a judge in the [Password Hashing Competition](http://password-hashing.net/). So he knows a thing or two about attacks on passwords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @kingkero in the comment above:  Make that two different classes.

I suggest that `HashedPassword` is only creatable through a factory method on `Password` (possibly using a `PasswordHashAlgorithm` service given as an argument), which will be used to create a hashed password after `Password` has validated the input.  Only `HashedPassword`s are persisted.

Comment: My `User` entity now contains `Password` and `PasswordHash`. To hash the passwords (in my `UserMapper`) I'm using the reliable built in PHP function `password_hash()`. I've got a `UserFactory` that has a `build()` method to build full blown user objects (with data returned from the `UserMapper`) and `buildFresh()` to build *new* user objects and still are to be persisted (it keeps the `Id` and `PasswordHash` null and uses `Password` instead). I had accepted your answer, but I'm a little bit confused the way you elaborated your answer what exactly to do. So could you expand on that, please?

Comment: Only my `Password` contains validation logic, `PasswordHash` doesn't because it would be impossible to actually validate the hash itself. I can only check if the hash is the proper length (60 characters).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I did not fully understand your question.  Why does your `User` contain `Password` *and* `PasswordHash`?  Wouldn't a `User` require a `Password` only?

Comment: Because my VO's contain validation logic. And `Password` (clean-text) is not the same as `PasswordHash` (hashed). `Password` is used when signing up new users, `PasswordHash` when retrieved from my database, because only hashed passwords are stored in my DB.

Comment: sorry, I meant "Wouldn't a `User` require a `HashedPassword` only?".  I don't see the need to add a `Password` to the `User` - the `Password` will validate the input upon construction, and if you then pass the `Password` to the `UserFactory`, the factory can hash the validated password and create the `User` with the hashed password.

Comment: Ah, so it would be better to let the `UserFactory` hash the password argument in the `build()` method and create the `PasswordHash` VO from that, instead of hashing it in the `UserMapper`? And do you mean to actually send in the `Password` VO to the `UserFactory` as well? Isn''t it actually the job of the `UserFactory` to create the corresponding VO's?

Comment: Yes, let the Factory hash the password. (I thought that `UserMapper` was your factory, sorry for the misunderstanding.) I have edited the answer.

Comment: Sure, you can also give the `UserFactory` a plain string and let it create the `Password` VO.  We are creating the `Password` VO in the client layer (UI) already (catching validation exceptions already in the client) and send it as part of the command, but that's personal taste.

Comment: One question though, how do you determine if the user has updated his password? I can't re-hash a hash and compare if its different from the old password.

Comment: But can't you hash the new password and check whether it's the same hash?  This is always done at password verification anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Client side password validation on the length could be on the textbox that contains the password string item.
After that, it should be considered a safe password (if the password store accepts it).

After that you should not set or get passwords from the password storage, but ask the store to verify the password for you.

So I think you are too late in checking the password strength, unless you can do it sooner.

Comment: Then you should setup a secured (https) connection.